# sdk-client-v2: ex createHttpMiddleware(options) now createHttpClient(options): no retryOnAbort?

Tags: commercetools

in the documentation of **sdk-middleware-http** about [createHttpMiddleware(options)](https://commercetools.github.io/nodejs/sdk/api/sdkMiddlewareHttp.html#createhttpmiddlewareoptions) I see

```
12. retryOnAbort (Boolean): Configure the client to retry an aborted request or not. Defaults to false.
```

But looks like this is not exists anymore in `@commercetools/sdk-client-v2/createHttpClient`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client timeout/retry settings are documented here:
https://github.com/commercetools/commercetools-sdk-typescript/blob/581ffecd93551322def7fa73484f90ef1f12a6e2/BEST_PRACTICES.md#configuring-the-timeout-parameter

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the TypeScript SDK (the "v2 SDK") then use the `HttpMiddlewareOptions` middleware and include it with your Client:

[image: TypeScriptSDKclient]

You can find out more about what middleware is available for the TypeScript SDK at https://docs.commercetools.com/sdk/javascript-sdk#middleware . There is also a [getting started guide](https://docs.commercetools.com/sdk/js-sdk-getting-started) to follow.

Comment: Please post your code directly to the post, no need of adding extra URLs that can become invalid in future.